# IOS Development downloading app before making it public

Tags: iphone, ios, submit, itunes

Hello i want to know if i can download my app before making it public some how after apple's approval process. I've already submitted my app (it's an update) and now i'm waiting for review. Is there anyway testing it before making it public?

Before uploading it i've checked making it public whenever i want to. So it won't be public unless i say so.

Comment: Promos only work if the app is published. They make only sense if the app is not free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your app is not published, it's not in the App Store, and therefore you cannot download it (from App Store).

The typical way to do this is archive the exact same configuration (i.e. release) with an AdHoc certificate and install it. It will work exactly as if you had downloaded it from App Store.

You can either install the ipa with iTunes, or if you want to give the app to other testers to test, use Over-The-Air, see http://iosdevelopertips.com/xcode/distribute-ad-hoc-applications-over-the-air-ota.html

Comment: Note that ad hoc uses a different certificate. This means if you upgrade to the app store version later, keychain data cannot be accessed.

Comment: Pardon? He won't send a version signed with his adhoc certificate to the app store. It's just used for testing. When publishing, he'll just change everything back to the way it was before

Comment: OK one more question can i publish my update and if don't like it remove it and place my old binary before the update i mean. All this methods i don't think they will help my situation

Comment: @JiaYow: Exactly. To be more clear: give out a test version of your app to somebody. This app will use a different cert than the one that will finally land on the store. Is the "tester" later updates to the real version from the store, the store app cannot read keychain content of the test version of the app. That's all I wanted to annotate. I think this is a major problem with Apple's policies. You cannot really test an upgrade. Upgrades can only be tested within the dev versions or after the app store version has been approved. But then it might be too late to notice that it does not work.

Comment: @MpampinosHolmens: as long as you did not release the app to app store you can "developer reject" it. If it has been published your previous version's binary is lost. I consider this a major drawback of Apple's App store. Even if you are going to resubmit the previous binaries they will have to be reviewed again and this takes time. IMHO Apple should come up with a possibility of versioning apps.

Comment: Yes that's really bad and Apple should fix it.